# Should I cache this object in c++ (SFML)

Tags: c++, caching, sfml

(I'm completely new to c++, but I have expierence in c# and java)

Hi, I'm creating a chess game in c++ (SFML) and I have a Piece class which has draw method. Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
void Piece::draw(sf::RenderWindow& p_window, bool p_selected) {
    if (p_selected) {
        sf::RectangleShape shape;
        shape.setFillColor(sf::Color(190,235,127));
        shape.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(221,237,142));
        shape.setOutlineThickness(3);
        shape.setSize(sf::Vector2f(80,80));
        shape.setPosition(sprite.getPosition());
        p_window.draw(shape);
    }

    p_window.draw(sprite);
}
```

If the piece is selected, I create RectangleShape (to let player know what piece is selected) , set its properties and then I draw it.

is this a good way of doing this?
Or should I cache the RectangleShape with setted properties and just update its position to the selected piece position?

Let me know if I missed something important, thanks for any answer.

Comment: You should absolutely cache that stuff. Drawing is something you will be doing a lot. And once you add a real shape / textures, the costs for *not* caching will explode.

Comment: i don't know if you understood my question, im caching the figure with texture on it, and i just draw it.

Comment: but i want a green square on the selected piece position

Comment: and the question is if i should cache this green Square

Comment: It's very opinion based. I personally think caching the rectangle shape would be such a tiny performance increase that it would not be worth your time reorganising the code,  unless you are drawing thousands of rectangles and have measured the rendering function as being slow. If caching it is simple, then sure, when you make future classes I would store it in the object, but I personally only go back and optimise things when I have measured they are slow and that slowness is a problem, when I know spending time elsewhere would not allow for a better performance increase. That's my opinion.

Comment: The other comment mentioned Textures, those would be an issue if you were loading them every frame, as those read from Storage which can make your program 100x of times slower, make sure you load Textures as little as possible.

Comment: Doing a quick test, drawing 10000 instances of a Piece class (with your render function, the sprite is blank though), on Debug mode I noticed about 10x slowdown, and on release mode I noticed about 2x slowdown. So, if drawing 10000 empty pieces is all you are doing, and you need twice the framerate, cache it. But then why stop there, going further, if you also use sf::VertexArray, you get an additional 2x speed up. The issue is the code gets more complex the more efficient it is. Since you can cache easily, do so next time, but I would not now when you could be doing other things.

Comment: As for textures, measuring on Release mod, storing once (using static) vs reloading every frame, I got a 133x performance increase. When compared to the x4 performance increase earlier, this is much more significant. Short story, four years ago, when I first started learning C++ with SFML and made a platformer. Rendering the blocks took so long. I made many optimisations, Vertex Arrays, only drawing the blocks within the range visible on screen, etc. A few months later I found out > 90% of the performance loss was because I used a std::list instead of a std::vector.

Comment: Not meaning to spam comments but I don't want to spread misinformation. Doing some performance tests now, std::list doesn't seem that much slower than std::vector, at least for iterating through all elements and rendering them, so clearly I must have done something else wrong four years ago.

Comment: @Lily vector vs list is all about cache locality. In a micro benchmark, you will only see the memory overhead for the next-element pointers in the list, but no performance penalty as the allocations are also in-order, back-to-back on the heap. That changes entirely if your benchmark isn't trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realistically, the performance impact of caching vs not caching an sf::RectangleShape is tiny, especially for a relatively simple program such as a chess game. Generally though, it is a good idea to cache variables that are used repeatedly each frame rather than creating them over and over again. I decided to write a small test case using the code you provided to measure the difference in performance over 10,000 draw calls. The result was a roughly 23% performance increase (1518ms vs 1030ms.) Here is the code I used so that you can test it yourself:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class Test {
public:
    static sf::RectangleShape rect;

    Test() {
        rect.setFillColor(sf::Color(190, 235, 127));
        rect.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(221, 237, 142));
        rect.setOutlineThickness(3);
        rect.setSize(sf::Vector2f(80, 80));
        rect.setPosition(0, 0);
    }

    void drawNoCache(sf::RenderWindow& p_window) {
        sf::RectangleShape shape;
        shape.setFillColor(sf::Color(190, 235, 127));
        shape.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(221, 237, 142));
        shape.setOutlineThickness(3);
        shape.setSize(sf::Vector2f(80, 80));
        shape.setPosition(0, 0);
        p_window.draw(shape);
    }


    void drawWithCache(sf::RenderWindow& p_window) {
        p_window.draw(rect);
    }
};

sf::RectangleShape Test::rect;

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(80, 80), "SFML");
    Test t;
    sf::Clock clock;
    clock.restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        window.clear(sf::Color(0, 0, 0));
        t.drawNoCache(window);
        window.display();
    }
    std::cout << clock.restart().asMilliseconds() << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        window.clear(sf::Color(0, 0, 0));
        t.drawWithCache(window);
        window.display();
    }
    std::cout << clock.restart().asMilliseconds() << std::endl;
}
```